# Is there any reason to not use <script setup> in vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html
I'm reading on the differences between the composition api and legacy options api with vue 3.
I've been confused on when I should use the setup function and the props option over the
script setup and defineProps. From what I've read on the faq,
"
Yes. You can use Composition API via the setup() option in an Options API component.

However, we only recommend doing so if you have an existing Options API codebase that needs to integrate with new features / external libraries written with Composition API.
"

So to be pedantic and asking for correctness, is using the setup function using options api?
If you were to start a new vue 3 project, would you use `<script setup>` in every component?
Is there ever a reason to not use `<script setup>`?

So far I have been using the setup function with the props options and I think the code plays nice and is readable, but I'm thinking this is not the correct way of going about things. Should I make evreything `<script setup>` and remove the setup function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So to be pedantic and asking for correctness, is using the setup function using options api?

Options API isn't identical to `script` block. Options API stands for component options that were replaced with composition API, namely `data`, `methods`, `computed`, `watch`, `mixins`.

> If you were to start a new vue 3 project, would you use  in every component? Is there ever a reason to not use ?

This is subjective, but there are reasons to avoid this.

`script setup` is DSL and not spec-compliant JavaScript. It's not transparent and not thoroughly documented, a considerable amount of the problems that are related to this syntax come from that the developers aren't fully aware of what code is doing, this can be confirmed only by debugging the compiled JavaScript code. This adds to a similar problem to `template` DSL, except that the latter is well-documented and there are other reasons for it to exists besides that it allows to write less code.

The syntax covers most common cases, but previously any extraordinary case required to [add additional `script` block](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#usage-alongside-normal-script) or refactor a component to use `script` instead of `script setup`. Some of these cases cannot be predicted at the time when a decision on component syntax is made. This is no longer a problem with the addition of [`defineOptions` macro](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineoptions).

There are still tools that don't fully support `script setup` syntax.

Vue [reactivity transforms](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html) is another example of syntax sugar that uses `$` dollar, etc macros for concise component code at the expense of its clarity and the compliance with ECMAScript standards.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this "script setup is DSL and not spec-compliant JavaScript."
I don't know what DSL is.

Comment: So it doesn't handle every case - I saw the three you sent me where you would still need a regular `<script>`...


If you want a consistent and maintainable code base, are you suggesting that using a script with a setup function is the best route? I'm sort of hunching that way.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language . It's a made-up language that resembles JS but works in its own way. In JS you'd expect that `import MyComp ...` is a no-op and will be tree-shaken, but in script setup it's added to `components` by magic, and so on. Yes, I'm personally recommending to use script function, it's a safer bet, despite that script setup is widely advertised. script setup can make the job done several percents faster but nobody knows how much time you'll lose on dealing with its restrictions and quirks, and common JS knowledge won't help with them.

Comment: Thanks this is an excellent answer and I think I fully understand whats going on now. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I think this is a good answer regardless of someone having a different opinion. From my experience with Vue (with Nuxt on my first project), the Composition API is a clear step forward with powerful possibilities. The Options API is easier to understand and friendlier,  so this new way does have some disadvantages. Also, with the `<script setup>` syntax, there is a big responsibility from the developer's perspective, but it's way more flexible, and it makes sense, at least for me. It allows developers be messy for sure, but the opposite is also true.

Comment: Like to the creator's arguments: https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/issues/55#issuecomment-504875870

Answer (score 2):

You can use `script setup`, or `setup()` inside of Options API.
Some people prefer Options API, the rest enjoys CAPI.

This is just a preference and allowing people to still use Options API since it's more accessible and easier to grasp (especially for beginners).

CAPI being aimed more towards advanced users or React hooks devs.