# How to refer to a private variable declared in <script> in <script setup>

Tags: vue.js

in the below posted code i am trying to display the result of the boolean expression `this.name_.length > 0 ? 'Yes' : 'No'` in the text interpolation `{{calculated}}`.
the problem i am facing lurks in the following code

```
const calculated = computed(() => {
      return this.name_.length > 0 ? 'Yes' : 'No'
    })
```

the compiler generates the following error when `this.name_` is used:

```
app.js:220 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name_')
```

when i remove the `this` keyword, it generates the following error:

```
error  'name_' is not defined  no-undef
```

please let me know how to refer to the member variable in `<script setup>`

**code**:

```
<template>
  <p>computedProps:{{ calculated }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  data() {
    const name_ = "ertz"
    const address_ = "aasf"
    const phone_ = "100 xx 50"
    return{
      name_,
      address_,
      phone_
    }
  }
};
</script>

<script setup>
    import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
    import { reactive,nextTick, ref, computed } from 'vue' 

    const calculated = computed(() => {
      return this.name_.length > 0 ? 'Yes' : 'No'
    })
</script>
```

Comment: What you're showing is not "script" but options api. You can use composition api in script and that's how it's normally done in vue 3.

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't use `this` in `<script setup>`
2. Options API data can be accessed through getCurrentInstance but it's not recommended (thanks [@EstusFlask](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus-flask))
3. Don't mix `Options API` with `Composition API`, if it not really necessary.

Just choose one `Vue API` and do all the code using it.

For **Options API** add

```
computed: 
    calculated() {
      return this.name_.length > 0 ? 'Yes' : 'No'
    }
```

For **Composition API** add

```
const name_ = ref("ertz")
const address_ = ref("aasf")
const phone_ = ref("100 xx 50")

const calculated = computed(() => {
  return name_.length > 0 ? 'Yes' : 'No'
})
```

Comment: i re-defined the data() option as you suggested, but the compiler generared a lot of errors, as if it does not accept or allow such definition of the data() option

Comment: Sorry, about defining `data()`, It's ok. I have overseen it.

Comment: options api data can be accessed through getCurrentInstance but it's not recomended

Comment: i have a question please, is any thing enclosed between <script></script> is considered options api? while any thing enclosed between <script setup> </script> is considered composition api?is that true?

Comment: @LetsamrIt code in <script></script> is written in Options API. `<script setup>` should have Composition API code.

Comment: @LetsamrIt More precisely, all options that are replaced with composition api are considered options api, i.e. data, methods, watch, computed options. <script> with props and setup options only are obviously can be considered composition api, this is what's shown in the docs

Comment: @EstusFlask would you please tell what is the difference then between the methods declared in <script> </> and those declared in <script setup></>

Comment: @LetsamrIt <script setup> is the body of setup function that could be specified <script> with some magic from Vue compiler that's mostly explained in official docs but isn't thoroughly documented, that's one of reasons use it with caution or avoid it at all. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74196753/is-there-any-reason-to-not-use-script-setup-in-vue3 for some more info